# elasticsearch, match all, for integer range search?

Tags: elasticsearch

Suppose I have a field to indicate an integer range between 1 and 7
(indicates age 1 through 7)

(1,5) (2,7)

I also have a special value `all` that means `ages don't matter`

I'd like to index and search this field in elasticsearch.

When user searches with `all` age, I'd like to return essentially `match_all`.
What's the proper value to put in elasticsearch index to support this type of search?

I also have null value for the field, when we are not sure about the age.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that Elasticsearch has a 'range' field type, so you're either stuck with a string, e.g. "(1,5)", where you couldn't find that age 2 was in there, or splitting into two fields, e.g. "age_low", "age_high".

With two fields, if age didn't matter, you could leave them blank, or set them to stupid values, e.g. (0, 200).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this from a performance standpoint is to index every integer in the range(s) in a byte field. Since fields can hold arrays you can simply search for a given age and find all document that match the given age range. For the "all" case just store the document with the values from 0 to 150.

If you want to stick to your current syntax than you can use [transforms](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-transform.html) to parse your '(x,y)...' string and store the values in the index (but not the _source JSON document).